# Reading file contents using C#

Tags: c#, file

I want to read the contents of following file types using C#:

1. RTF
2. PDF
3. HTML
4. MS Word

Is there any common API in .Net for reading all file type contents?

Comment: opening the file and reading its contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in support for reading most of those file types. HTML is plain text so you can use the System.IO/StreamReader to read it, but you must parse it yourself.

There are third party components which will read these file types, but I am not sure if there is one all encompassing component.

For PDFs, I believe [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) allows you to read.

For RTF/Word, You can use the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) before it's a very powerful product it's reasonably pricey so would only recommend it if your application also needs to create new word/pdf/rtf documents.

I agree with the other comments about just using System.IO for reading HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to full-text index the data, look into using [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), it can handle those file types.